# Concatenating Series using the addition (+) operator?

Tags: python, pandas, series

So this is more of a question than a problem i have.

I wanted to `.append()` some pandas series' together and without thinking i just did `total=series1+series2+series3`.

The length of each series is 2199902,171175, and 178989 respectively and `sum(pd.isnull(i) for i in total)` = 2214596

P.S all 3 series' had no null values to start with, is it something to do with merging 3 series' of different lengths which creates missing values? Even if that is the case why aer 2,214,596 null values created?

Comment: Append != sum, are you looking for `pd.concat([s1, s2, s3])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to *append* series, you're doing it wrong. The `+` operator calls `.add` which ends up *adding* each corresponding elements in the series. If your series are not aligned, this results in a lot of `NaN`s being generated.

If you're looking to *append* these together into one long series, you can use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], ignore_index=True)
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

If you're going to use `append`, you can do this in a loop, or with `reduce`:

```
s = s1

for i in [s2, s3]:
    s = s.append(i, ignore_index=True)

s
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y: x.append(y, ignore_index=True), [s1, s2, s3])

0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

Both solutions generalise to multiple series quite nicely, but they are slow in comparison to `pd.concat` or `np.concatenate`.

Comment: I think we can using reduce rather than for loop :-)

Comment: @Wen Interesting... I was typing that out as you posted.

Comment: Or if you're going full-functional, `reduce(partial(pd.Series.append, ignore_index=True), (s1, s2, s3))` :P

Answer (score 2):

If `sum` Series all index are align. So if some index exist in `series1` and not in another `Series`, get `NaN`s.

So need [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with `fill_value=0`:

```
s = s1.add(s2, fill_value=0).add(s3, fill_value=0)
```

Sample:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,4,5])
s2 = pd.Series([4,7], index=[10,11])
s3 = pd.Series([40,70], index=[2,4])

s = s1.add(s2, fill_value=0).add(s3, fill_value=0)
print (s)
0      1.0
1      2.0
2     44.0
3      5.0
4     70.0
10     4.0
11     7.0
dtype: float64
```

But if need append them together (or use `concat` as mentioned `cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ`):

```
s = s1.append(s2, ignore_index=True).append(s3, ignore_index=True)
print (s)
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

And numpy alternative:

```
#alternative, thanks cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - np.concatenate([s1, s2, s3])
s = pd.Series(np.concatenate([s1.values, s2.values, s3.values]))

print (s)
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

If want use `+` for append then need convert Series to lists:

```
s = pd.Series(s1.tolist() + s2.tolist() + s3.tolist())
print (s)
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     5
4     4
5     7
6    40
7    70
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `np.concatenate([s1, s2, s3])` works just like that.